# Microsoft Word "DOT" not showing up after the table

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, cell-format, symbols

The "dot" as highlighted below in the screenshot does not show up in my another Word document. It only appears in inside the table and not at the right edge of the table. See the difference of the pictures below.

[image: "dots" everywhere]

[image: "dots" only inside the table]

May I know how to enable it? What are the dot called as highlighted so I can search the solution from internet?

Comment: What happens if you select the ***entire*** table and change the font size?

Answer (score 0):

#### What are the dot called as highlighted?

They are called **Cell markers**.

If you format your rows the **end-of-row markers** will be displayed.

> In tables you will see one additional character, the universal
>   monetary symbol, Unicode character 00A4 (`¤`), which displays
>   variously at various point sizes and magnifications but upon close
>   inspection is seen to be a circle with four lines radiating from the
>   corners. This is the end-of-cell marker. It is a little like the
>   paragraph mark in that it contains paragraph formatting for the last
>   (or only) paragraph in the cell, but it also holds formatting for the
>   cell.
>
> **The same mark at the end of each row is the (wait for it) end-of-row marker, which serves a similar purpose with regard to row
>   formatting.**

Source [Nonprinting Formatting Marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It's the currency symbol `¤` which is used for indicating the ***end-of-cell*** or ***end-of-row*** when paragraph marks are shown. To turn them on select *File* > *Options* > *Display* and select the items you want under *Always show these formatting marks on the screen*. See [Show or hide formatting marks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c2d8a607-5646-4165-8b08-bd68f9d172a0)

> This is the end-of-cell marker. It is a little like the paragraph mark in that it contains paragraph formatting for the last (or only) paragraph in the cell, but it also holds formatting for the cell. The same mark at the end of each row is the (wait for it) end-of-row marker, which serves a similar purpose with regard to row formatting.¤
>
> http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm

It can't be turned off for the end of rows only and and show at the end of cells. However because it holds the **formatting** for the whole row as well as cells, you can **make it invisible** by setting the foreground color the same as background

[image: table with end-of-cell/row symbols]

In the above example I've selected the 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> row of the first table, and set the text color to white, so the marks "disappear" on those lines. Then I select the cells in the first row of the first table and set their foreground back to black and as you can see, it looks like the marks only appear inside the table

I can also **do that quickly for the whole table** like in the second table by clicking the cross [table selecting symbol](https://www.howtogeek.com/221131/how-to-select-all-or-part-of-a-table-in-word/) at the top-left corner, set foreground to black and then put the mouse on top of the first column and select all the columns before changing their text to black

I'm not sure how your other file was created but I think the same technique was used

## See also

- [What is the Word editing symbol that looks a small sunburst and what does is mean](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/what-is-the-word-editing-symbol-that-looks-a-small/cbace2b4-7cee-4099-901a-68de8720979a?auth=1)
- [What is this non-printing character? (¤)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8acb4bf3-1bc7-4926-9ed3-4d7f2cd04aad/what-is-this-nonprinting-character-?forum=word)